# SQL AVG() and ORDER BY combination

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table with fields like this:

```
F1 40
F2 30
F3 120
F4 77
F5 12
F6..
F7..
```

etc.

I would like to retrieve the average value of any given field, but sort them in descending order.

```
$query = "SELECT AVG(F1) as F1, AVG(F2) as F2, AVG(F3) as F3, (..)
     FROM survey";
```

The above would retrieve the average values okay, but how could I output them in descending order?

Comment: You said that F1, F2, etc. are rows, but they are columns in your query? What are the columns of your table?

Comment: sorry Hamza, that was confusing, - these are the field names. I've corrected the question accordingly.

Comment: Since there is a finite, and relatively small, number of fields (columns), can you just grab them all and sort them in code?

Answer (score 0):

The normal `ORDER BY` approach should work even with aggregate functions like `AVG()` or `SUM()`. You should be able to access to fields directly be their alias (such as `F1 DESC`), but if this doesn't work you may need to use a different approach.

Try using the query:

```
SELECT
    AVG(F1) as F1_avg, AVG(F2) as F2_avg, AVG(F3) as F3_avg
FROM
    survey
ORDER BY
    F1_avg DESC;
```

Based on your current query, you'll only be receiving a single row which defeats the purpose of the `ORDER BY`. However, if you are using a `GROUP BY` (and just not showing it in the question), the above should work well.

Comment: I understand ... but what I'm looking for is to sort the resulting average values in descending order. Is there a way to do that with SQL or would I have to sort the resulting values by myself / code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... are you saying you want to sort the columns themselves and not the returned rows? In other words, if `F2` has a higher average that `F1`, it is the first column instead? If that's the case, that's not possible (unless you build a ridiculously robust `UNION` statement)